# Convert single row to multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have downloaded a year long data from NOAA. The problem is that the data downloaded has text also in it. So, I found the pattern for the data lines and extracted it. The code that I have used is as follows:

```
url <- "http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/data_menu.shtml?bdate=20080101&edate=20081231&wl_sensor_hist=W2&relative=&datum=6&unit=0&shift=s&stn=8737048+Mobile+State+Docks%2C+AL&type=Historic+Tide+Data&format=View+Data"
download.file(url,destfile="data/mobile-docks-2008.dat")

mob2008 <- readLines("data/mobile-docks-2008.dat")
head(mob2008)

# Find pattern to separate data
pat <- grep(pattern="([0-9]+)\\s[0-9]",mob2008)

jd1 <- data.frame(mob2008[pat])
head(jd1)
> head(jd1)
                            mob2008.pat.
1 8737048 20080101 00:00   0.125   0.270
2 8737048 20080101 01:00   0.090   0.220
3 8737048 20080101 02:00   0.070   0.167
4 8737048 20080101 03:00   0.061   0.093
5 8737048 20080101 04:00   0.057   0.002
6 8737048 20080101 05:00   0.052  -0.108
```

How can I change the single row to multiple columns in R ? Seems to be a trivial problem but I am stuck on this.

The problem is the dataframe jd1 has only one column. I need to have 5 columns on each row.

Comment: `data` is the folder in my working directory. You just need to replace data

Comment: If you are scraping data from webpages regularly, it may be worthwhile to look into the `XML` package. It has the function `htmlTreeParse` that could be used to get around the regexp search in your example. If you are downloading data just from time to time, using `htmlTreeParse` is, however, a bit of an overkill. :)

Comment: @cryo111 : Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into `XML` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for reshape2 or strsplit.

Just:

```
> jd1 <- read.table(text=mob2008[pat])
> head(jd1)
       V1       V2    V3    V4     V5
1 8737048 20080101 00:00 0.125  0.270
2 8737048 20080101 01:00 0.090  0.220
3 8737048 20080101 02:00 0.070  0.167
4 8737048 20080101 03:00 0.061  0.093
5 8737048 20080101 04:00 0.057  0.002
6 8737048 20080101 05:00 0.052 -0.108
```

Answer (score 3):

```
R> jd1 = readLines(textConnection("1 8737048 20080101 00:00   0.125   0.270
+ 2 8737048 20080101 01:00   0.090   0.220
+ 3 8737048 20080101 02:00   0.070   0.167
+ 4 8737048 20080101 03:00   0.061   0.093
+ 5 8737048 20080101 04:00   0.057   0.002
+ 6 8737048 20080101 05:00   0.052  -0.108"))
R> jd1 = data.frame(mob2008.pat. = jd1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
R> jd1
                              mob2008.pat.
1 1 8737048 20080101 00:00   0.125   0.270
2 2 8737048 20080101 01:00   0.090   0.220
3 3 8737048 20080101 02:00   0.070   0.167
4 4 8737048 20080101 03:00   0.061   0.093
5 5 8737048 20080101 04:00   0.057   0.002
6 6 8737048 20080101 05:00   0.052  -0.108
R> dim(jd1)
[1] 6 1
R> jd2 = strsplit(jd1[[1]], " ")
R> jd2 = lapply(jd2, function(x) x[x != ""] )
R> jd2 = do.call(rbind, jd2)
R> data.frame(jd2)
  X1      X2       X3    X4    X5     X6
1  1 8737048 20080101 00:00 0.125  0.270
2  2 8737048 20080101 01:00 0.090  0.220
3  3 8737048 20080101 02:00 0.070  0.167
4  4 8737048 20080101 03:00 0.061  0.093
5  5 8737048 20080101 04:00 0.057  0.002
6  6 8737048 20080101 05:00 0.052 -0.108
```

This has 6 columns, but removing the row number column is easy enough and will give you the desired 5 columns.

Comment: @Jdbaba no problem. give yourself a check mark! your solution is much better than mine

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my question using package reshape2 and function `colsplit`

The solution is as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
> jd1<- colsplit(mob2008[pat],pattern="\\s+" ,names=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5"))
> head(jd1)
       V1       V2    V3    V4     V5
1 8737048 20080101 00:00 0.125  0.270
2 8737048 20080101 01:00 0.090  0.220
3 8737048 20080101 02:00 0.070  0.167
4 8737048 20080101 03:00 0.061  0.093
5 8737048 20080101 04:00 0.057  0.002
6 8737048 20080101 05:00 0.052 -0.108
```